# Connect Spring MVC with aws documentDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mvc, aws-documentdb

I'm using mongoDB with aws ec2 instance it's working fine and I've moved mongoDB to aws documentDB, So i'm not able to connect documentDB with same code, So any one can u please help me if you have idea.

Here is my connection code in Spring MVC:

```
@Bean
public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws UnknownHostException {
   return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(env.getProperty("mongo.database.host"), Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("mongo.database.port"))), env.getProperty("mongo.database.name"));
}
```

Spring, Hibernet and mongoDB version:
spring -4.2.5
spring-data-MongoDB -1.10.14
mongo-java-driver -3.5.0

Comment: What problem are you having specifically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To connect using TLS, you will have to import the rds-combined-ca-bundle file.
I would suggest go through: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect.html and check the sample logic given for java.

Answer (score 1):

Now my documnetDB connection issue is resolve without SSL, I just have used following code for connection:

**mongo.property** :
mongo.database.uri=mongodb://:@cluster url:27017/?replicaSet=rs0

connection code :

```
@Bean
    public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws UnknownHostException {
       return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClientURI(env.getProperty("mongo.database.uri")));
    }
```

Still I'm having issue with SSL.

Answer (score 0):

download this file `rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem` and keep it in resources section.
this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect_programmatically.html) provides great start and it shows sample program for java